# How to align virtual images with solid models

Tags: c++, augmented-reality

I used aruco to build an AR project that uses four points to register //via the ICP algorithm. The point at which the marker is pasted is obtained by solving the tevc in the PNP. The constructed virtual object relies on the point of the VTK world coordinate system, but I got the wrong result, which I have not solved so far. The following is my core code.

I tested the transformation matrix separately and the coordinates I got, they seem to be correct

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    initTitle();
    initBackGround();
    initToolBar();
    initConnect();
    initTableRightMenu();
    initTable();
    //ui.toolRB->setVisible(true);

    timer = new QTimer(this);

    movingPoints.push_back(new PointSelf());
    movingPoints.push_back(new PointSelf());
    movingPoints.push_back(new PointSelf());
    movingPoints.push_back(new PointSelf());
}

void MainWindow::normalSyle()
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera> style =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera>::New();
    this->ui.openGLWidgetRB->GetRenderWindow()->GetInteractor()->SetInteractorStyle(style);
    this->ui.openGLWidgetRB->GetRenderWindow()->GetInteractor()->RemoveObservers(vtkCommand::RightButtonPressEvent);
}

void MainWindow::initTable()
{
    ui.tableMeasure->setColumnCount(4);
    ui.tableMeasure->setRowCount(8);
    ui.tableMeasure->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section {background-color:rgb(181, 184, 182);color: black;}");
    ui.tableMeasure->horizontalHeader()->setDisabled(true);

    ui.tableMeasure->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() << "name" << "X" << "Y" << "Z");

    ui.tableMeasure->setItem(0, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(QStringLiteral("markerId=0")));
    ui.tableMeasure->setItem(1, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(QStringLiteral("markerId=1")));
    ui.tableMeasure->setItem(2, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(QStringLiteral("markerId=2")));
    ui.tableMeasure->setItem(3, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(QStringLiteral("markerId=3")));
    ui.tableMeasure->setItem(4, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(QStringLiteral("markerId=4")));
    ui.tableMeasure->setItem(5, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(QStringLiteral("markerId=5")));

    ui.tableMeasure->setItem(6, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(QStringLiteral("Point1")));
    ui.tableMeasure->setItem(7, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(QStringLiteral("Point2")));
}

double* MainWindow::dealPointPick()
{
    QSize size;
    size = this->ui.openGLWidgetRB->size();
    double *picked = new double[3];
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellPicker> cellPicker =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellPicker>::New();
    cellPicker->SetTolerance(0.005);
    cellPicker->Pick(rightClikPoint.x(), size.height() - rightClikPoint.y() - 1, 0, ui.openGLWidgetRB->GetRenderWindow()->GetRenderers()->GetFirstRenderer());
    cellPicker->GetPickPosition(picked);
    if (cellPicker->GetPointId() < 0) return nullptr;
    return picked;
}

void MainWindow::dealMarkerId0()
{
     double* position = dealPointPick();
     pickedPoints.push_back(position);

    if (position == nullptr) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ui.tableMeasure->setItem(0, 1 + i, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(position[i])));
    }

}

void MainWindow::dealMarkerId1()
{
     double* position = dealPointPick();
    pickedPoints.push_back(position);

    if (position == nullptr) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ui.tableMeasure->setItem(1, 1 + i, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(position[i])));
    }
}

void MainWindow::dealMarkerId2()
{
     double* position = dealPointPick();
    pickedPoints.push_back(position);

    if (position == nullptr) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ui.tableMeasure->setItem(2, 1 + i, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(position[i])));
    }
}

void MainWindow::dealMarkerId3()
{
     double* position = dealPointPick();
    pickedPoints.push_back(position);

    if (position == nullptr) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ui.tableMeasure->setItem(3, 1 + i, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(position[i])));
    }
}

void MainWindow::openCamera()
{
    capture.open(0);
    capture.set(3, 1920);
    capture.set(4, 1080);

    if (!capture.isOpened())  
    {
        cout << "camera is not open" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "camera is open" << endl;

        connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateWindow()));
        timer->start(20);
    }
}


Mat cameraMatrix(3, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type);
Mat distCoeffs(4, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);

void MainWindow::updateWindow()
{

    capture >> frame;
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(0, 0) = 720;
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(0, 1) = 0;
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(0, 2) = 640;

    cameraMatrix.at<double>(1, 0) = 0;
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(1, 1) = 720;
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(1, 2) = 360;

    cameraMatrix.at<double>(2, 0) = 0;
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(2, 1) = 0;
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(2, 2) = 0;

    distCoeffs.at<double>(0, 0) = 0;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(1, 0) = 0;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(2, 0) = 0;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(3, 0) = 0;

    cv::cvtColor(frame, image, COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    aruco::detectMarkers(image, dictionary, corners, ids, detectorParams, rejectPoint);

        if (ids.size() > 0)
        {

            cv::aruco::drawDetectedMarkers(frame, corners, ids);
            for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    circle(frame, Point(corners[i][j].x, corners[i][j].y), 3, Scalar(255, 0, 0));
                }

                std::vector<Point3f> objectPoints;
                objectPoints.push_back(Point3f(-15, -15, 0));
                objectPoints.push_back(Point3f(15, -15, 0));
                objectPoints.push_back(Point3f(15, 15, 0));
                objectPoints.push_back(Point3f(-15, 15, 0));

                Mat rvec(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                Mat tvec(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                Mat rotationMatrix(3, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                Mat totM;
                cv::solvePnP(objectPoints, corners[i], cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec);
                drawFrameAxes(frame, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec, 50);

                if (ids[i] == 0)
                {
                    Mat rvec0(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                    Mat tvec0(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                    Mat rotationMatrix0(3, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                    Mat totM0;
                    cv::solvePnP(objectPoints, corners[i], cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec0, tvec0);
                    drawFrameAxes(frame, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec0, tvec0, 50);

                    /*for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        double temp0 = tvec0.at<double>(i, 0);
                        movingPoints[0][i] = temp0;
                    }*/
                    movingPoints[0]->x = tvec0.at<double>(0, 0);
                    movingPoints[0]->y = tvec0.at<double>(1, 0);
                    movingPoints[0]->z = tvec0.at<double>(2, 0);
                }

                if (ids[i] == 1)
                {
                    Mat rvec1(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                    Mat tvec1(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                    Mat rotationMatrix1(3, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                    Mat totM1;
                    cv::solvePnP(objectPoints, corners[i], cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec1, tvec1);
                    drawFrameAxes(frame, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec1, tvec1, 50);

                    movingPoints[1]->x = tvec1.at<double>(0, 0);
                    movingPoints[1]->y = tvec1.at<double>(1, 0);
                    movingPoints[1]->z = tvec1.at<double>(2, 0);

                }

                if (ids[i] == 2)
                {
                    Mat rvec2(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                    Mat tvec2(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                    Mat rotationMatrix1(3, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                    Mat totM2;
                    cv::solvePnP(objectPoints, corners[i], cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec2, tvec2);
                    drawFrameAxes(frame, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec2, tvec2, 50);

                    movingPoints[2]->x = tvec2.at<double>(0, 0);
                    movingPoints[2]->y = tvec2.at<double>(1, 0);
                    movingPoints[2]->z = tvec2.at<double>(2, 0);
                }

                if (ids[i] == 3)
                {
                    Mat rvec3(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                    Mat tvec3(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                    Mat rotationMatrix1(3, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type);
                    Mat totM3;
                    cv::solvePnP(objectPoints, corners[i], cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec3, tvec3);
                    drawFrameAxes(frame, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec3, tvec3, 50);

                    movingPoints[3]->x = tvec3.at<double>(0, 0);
                    movingPoints[3]->y = tvec3.at<double>(1, 0);
                    movingPoints[3]->z = tvec3.at<double>(2, 0);
                }

                cv::Rodrigues(rvec, rotationMatrix);
                camPointMatrix->Identity();
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        camPointMatrix->SetElement(i, j, rotationMatrix.at<double>(i, j));
                    }
                    camPointMatrix->SetElement(i, 3, tvec.at<double>(i, 0));
                }
            }

        }
    cv::cvtColor(image, frame, COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    cv::imshow("image", frame);
      cv::waitKey(10);`enter code here`

}

 QString dirname;
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMImageReader> dicomReader = 
   vtkSmartPointer< vtkDICOMImageReader>::New();

 vtkSmartPointer<vtkSmartVolumeMapper> volumeMapper = 
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkSmartVolumeMapper>::New();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolumeProperty> volumeProperty = 
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolumeProperty>::New();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction> compositeOpacity = 
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction>::New();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction> volumeGradientOpacity =
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction>::New();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkColorTransferFunction> color = 
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkColorTransferFunction>::New();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolume> volume1 =
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolume>::New();

void MainWindow::dicomImport()
{
    dirname = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, "readDicom", "../CT");
    if (dirname == "") return;
    dicomReader->SetDataByteOrderToLittleEndian();
    dicomReader->SetDirectoryName(dirname.toLatin1().data());
    dicomReader->Update();

    volumeMapper->SetInputData(dicomReader->GetOutput());

    volumeProperty->SetInterpolationTypeToLinear();
    volumeProperty->SetAmbient(0.4);
    volumeProperty->SetDiffuse(0.6);
    volumeProperty->SetSpecular(0.2);

    compositeOpacity->AddPoint(120, 0.00);
    compositeOpacity->AddPoint(200, 0.40);
    compositeOpacity->AddPoint(1500, 0.60);
    volumeProperty->SetScalarOpacity(compositeOpacity);

    volumeGradientOpacity->AddPoint(100, 0.0);
    volumeGradientOpacity->AddPoint(190, 0.5);
    volumeGradientOpacity->AddPoint(300, 1.0);

    color->AddRGBPoint(0.000, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00);
    color->AddRGBPoint(64.00, 1.00, 0.52, 0.30);
    color->AddRGBPoint(4000.0, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00);
    color->AddRGBPoint(1200.0, 0.20, 0.20, 0.20);
    volumeProperty->SetColor(color);

    volume1->SetMapper(volumeMapper);
    volume1->SetProperty(volumeProperty);

    render->AddVolume(volume1);
    render->ResetCamera();
    render->GetActiveCamera()->ParallelProjectionOn();
    render->ResetCameraClippingRange();
    this->ui.openGLWidgetRB->GetRenderWindow()->GetInteractor()->RemoveObservers(vtkCommand::RightButtonPressEvent);
    this->ui.openGLWidgetRB->GetRenderWindow()->Render();
}

void MainWindow::SVDRegistration()
{
    double firstArrayPoints[3][4] = { 0.0 };
    double OriginPoints[3][4] = { 0.0 };
    double TargetPoint[3][4] = { 0.0 };
    fixedPoints[4][3] = { 0.0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        fixedPoints[i][0] = pickedPoints[i][0];
        fixedPoints[i][1] = pickedPoints[i][1];
        fixedPoints[i][2] = pickedPoints[i][2];            
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        OriginPoints[0][i] = fixedPoints[i][0];
        OriginPoints[1][i] = fixedPoints[i][1];
        OriginPoints[2][i] = fixedPoints[i][2];

        TargetPoint[0][i] = movingPoints[i]->x;
        TargetPoint[1][i] = movingPoints[i]->y;
        TargetPoint[2][i] = movingPoints[i]->z;
    }

    Eigen::MatrixXd OriginMatrix(3, 4);
    Eigen::MatrixXd TargetMatrix(3, 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            OriginMatrix(i, j) = OriginPoints[i][j];
            TargetMatrix(i, j) = TargetPoint[i][j];
        }
    }

    double MassPointOrigin[3] = { 0.0 };
    double MassPointTarget[3] = { 0.0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        MassPointOrigin[0] += OriginPoints[0][i];
        MassPointOrigin[1] += OriginPoints[1][i];
        MassPointOrigin[2] += OriginPoints[2][i];

        MassPointTarget[0] += TargetPoint[0][i];
        MassPointTarget[1] += TargetPoint[1][i];
        MassPointTarget[2] += TargetPoint[2][i];
    }

    MassPointOrigin[0] = MassPointOrigin[0] / 4;
    MassPointOrigin[1] = MassPointOrigin[1] / 4;
    MassPointOrigin[2] = MassPointOrigin[2] / 4;

    MassPointTarget[0] = MassPointTarget[0] / 4;
    MassPointTarget[1] = MassPointTarget[1] / 4;
    MassPointTarget[2] = MassPointTarget[2] / 4;

    double OriginPointsAfterM[3][4] = { 0.0 };
    double TargetPointAfterM[3][4] = { 0.0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        OriginPointsAfterM[0][i] = OriginPoints[0][i] - MassPointOrigin[0];
        OriginPointsAfterM[1][i] = OriginPoints[1][i] - MassPointOrigin[1];
        OriginPointsAfterM[2][i] = OriginPoints[2][i] - MassPointOrigin[2];

        TargetPointAfterM[0][i] = TargetPoint[0][i] - MassPointTarget[0];
        TargetPointAfterM[1][i] = TargetPoint[1][i] - MassPointTarget[1];
        TargetPointAfterM[2][i] = TargetPoint[2][i] - MassPointTarget[2];
    }

    Eigen::MatrixXd MatrixOriginAM(3, 4);
    Eigen::MatrixXd MatrixTarget(3, 4);
    Eigen::MatrixXd MatrixTargetAM(4, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            MatrixOriginAM(i, j) = OriginPointsAfterM[i][j];
            MatrixTarget(i, j) = TargetPointAfterM[i][j];
        }
    }

    MatrixTargetAM = MatrixTarget.transpose();
    Eigen::MatrixXd WMatrix = MatrixOriginAM * MatrixTargetAM;

    Eigen::JacobiSVD <Eigen::MatrixXd> svd(WMatrix, Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV);
    Eigen::MatrixXd UMatrix = svd.matrixU();
    Eigen::MatrixXd right_singular_vectors = svd.matrixV();
    Eigen::MatrixXd VTMatrix = right_singular_vectors.transpose();
    Eigen::MatrixXd RotationMatrix = UMatrix * VTMatrix;

    double Rotate[3][3] = { 0.0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            Rotate[i][j] = RotationMatrix(i, j);
        }
    }

    Eigen::MatrixXd MassCentreOfTarget(3, 1);
    Eigen::MatrixXd MassCentreOfOrigin(3, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        MassCentreOfTarget(i, 0) = MassPointTarget[i];
        MassCentreOfOrigin(i, 0) = MassPointOrigin[i];
    }

    Eigen::MatrixXd TranslationMatrix = MassCentreOfOrigin - RotationMatrix * MassCentreOfTarget;

    double Translation[3] = { 0.0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Translation[i] = TranslationMatrix(i, 0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            ReturnMatrix[i][j] = Rotate[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ReturnMatrix[i][3] = Translation[i];
    }

    ReturnMatrix[3][3] = 1;

    double deepCopyMatrix[16] = {0.0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        deepCopyMatrix[i * 4 + 0] = ReturnMatrix[i][0];
        deepCopyMatrix[i * 4 + 1] = ReturnMatrix[i][1];
        deepCopyMatrix[i * 4 + 2] = ReturnMatrix[i][2];
        deepCopyMatrix[i * 4 + 3] = ReturnMatrix[i][3];
    }

    transMatrix->DeepCopy(deepCopyMatrix);

    volume1->SetUserMatrix(transMatrix);

    render->AddVolume(volume1);
    render->Render();
    this->ui.openGLWidgetRB->GetRenderWindow()->GetInteractor()->RemoveObservers(vtkCommand::RightButtonPressEvent);
    this->ui.openGLWidgetRB->GetRenderWindow()->Render();
}

void MainWindow::stlImport()
{
    stlReader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkSTLReader>::New();
    QString filename;
    filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, QStringLiteral("��ȡSTL"), "../", "*.stl;*./STL");
    if (filename == "") return;
    stlReader->SetFileName(filename.toUtf8().data());
    stlReader->Update();
    displayClipData(stlReader->GetOutput());
}

void MainWindow::displayClipData(vtkPolyData *input)
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = 
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();

    mapper->SetInputData(input);
    mapper->ScalarVisibilityOff();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    actor->SetMapper(mapper);
    actor->GetProperty()->SetColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    actor->GetProperty()->SetSpecular(0.5);

    actor->VisibilityOn();
    render->AddActor(actor);
    //render->SetBackground(0.157, 0.157, 0.157);
    render->ResetCamera();
    render->GetActiveCamera()->ParallelProjectionOn();
    render->ResetCameraClippingRange();
    this->ui.openGLWidgetRB->GetRenderWindow()->GetInteractor()->RemoveObservers(vtkCommand::RightButtonPressEvent);

    this->ui.openGLWidgetRB->GetRenderWindow()->Render();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.